# How to import csv to az storage table

Tags: azure, azure-storage, import-csv

Am trying to upload csv file to the azure table storage, which has 1000 + records and 6 columns, as shown below as Csvheadres, unfortunately, ended up with an error.do I need to add partition key and row key columns?

the CSV columns(CsvHeaders)
res1
res2
res3
res4
res5
res6

```
$storageAccountKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName).Value[0]
    $ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey
    $table = Get-AzStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $ctx 
    
    $CsvContents = Import-Csv -Path $Path
    $CsvHeaders = ($CsvContents[0] | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty).Name | Where{$_ -ne "RowKey" -and $_ -ne "PartitionKey"}
    
    Foreach($CsvContent in $CsvContents)
    {
        $PartitionKey = $CsvContent.PartitionKey
        $RowKey = $CsvContent.RowKey
        $Entity = New-Object "Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.DynamicTableEntity" "$PartitionKey", "$RowKey"
    
        Foreach($CsvHeader in $CsvHeaders)
        {
            $Value = $CsvContent.$CsvHeader
            $Entity.Properties.Add($CsvHeader, $Value)
        }
        Write-Verbose "Inserting the entity into table storage."
        $result = $Table.Execute([Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableOperation]::Insert($Entity))
    }
```

Comment: Whats the error message?

Comment: @burna  thanks for reply  The error "You can not call a metod on the null-values expression"

Comment: in your ps script, one of the source line is not checking null but trying to call method on it. Debug your PS script..[refer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/ise/how-to-debug-scripts-in-windows-powershell-ise?view=powershell-7.2)